# How to change only specific letters within a word us bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains addresses like:
`0x0003ffff`
`0x0003ffff`
`0x0000ffff`
`0x0000ffff`
`0x003fffff`
`0x05ffffff`
`0x3fffffff`
`0x000000ff`
There can be 'n' number of such addresses in that file , i want the addresses changed to

`0x0003FFB0`
`0x0003FFB0`
`0x0000FFB0`
`0x0000FFB0`
`0x003FFFB0`
`0x05FFFFB0`
`0x3FFFFFB0`
`0x000000B0`
For all the 'n' addresses.
What i basically want is to change the last 2 'ff's into 'B0' and the remaining 'f's into 'F'
How can i do that using bash scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed --in-place 's/\(0x000[0-9]\)ffff/\1FFB0/' file
```

Try it without the `--in-place` flag first to make sure it's what you want.

In case, like Nikhilesh Sharma pointed out, you might have more F's than indicated in your question, you can use the following.  I'm assuming you have GNU sed.  Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll give you the longer, but posix friendly, version.

```
sed --in-place 's/\(0x[0-9f]\{6\}\)ff/\U\1B0/' file
```

[Here's a good tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to cut your teeth on sed.

Comment: I'll add that `sed` is an essential part of the standard UNIX tool belt. It's well worth investing some time to learn its basic functionality: [A great sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: But what if there is an address `0x02FFFFFF` or `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: @NikhileshSharma Yeah I just thought of that.  It's not in the OP's examples, but I'll give a solution for it anyways.

Comment: @NikhileshSharma aaaaaand I just noticed that you ARE the OP.  Did my edits work for you?

Comment: @TimPote the second solution you gave me is changing the 'f' into 'F' but it is not changing the last two 'ff' into 'B0'

Comment: @NikhileshSharma Sorry, I had a typo.  Try the second solution now.

Comment: @TimPote i am not sure what's happening but there are no changes made in the file when i run this command in the terminal

Comment: @NikhileshSharma Is it spitting out anything?

Comment: @NikhileshSharma No problem.  I don't usually ask, but since you're new I'm not sure you know about it. If my answer helped you, can you hit the accept checkmark next to the answer?

Comment: @TimPote, use `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `[0-9f]`

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah I thought about doing that, but the OP requested specifically that the f's should be capitalized so I went with the more precise version.  However, it does seem like what they *actually* wanted was to capitalize all of the hex letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. your input file is called input.txt
2. all addresses start at column 1
3. you want to keep the first 8 characters
4. all addresses end with ff

then this could work (at least it works for your input):

```
cat input.txt | cut -b1-8 | tr f F | sed s/$/B0/g
```

Comment: [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  `cut` can take files directly.

Comment: I know, but I prefer the way I wrote it for two reasons: (1) it visually flows better, like a pipeline and (2) it's easier to insert some other process before the cut. I don't think the performance hit is anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gawk, use numeric operations instead of string operations

```
gawk '
  {n = strtonum($1)} 
  (n % 0x100) == 0xff {printf("0x%08X\n", n - 0x4f)}
'
```